# Creating my custom security role and custom user group tables, to implement custom authorization for my asp.net mvc web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an Intranet Asp.net mvc with windows authentication enabled. I am building an asset management application, and I need to define user groups and security roles. For example I have a group that contains senior HR employees; this group will be linked to a security role. The security role will allow for example to add new vehicles, but only allow reading the information about IT assets such as PC, etc.

But since I am working on intranet and the users exists in the Active Directory, and I want to link the user groups to customize security role. **So is it a recommended approach to use my own userGroups table and securityRole table to store the information about the user groups and their security roles**.
Currently I only use the users from AD , but stores the info about user groups and security roles inside my custom tables. As this will give me more flexibility of implementing the requirements, OR it is recommended to use the build-in groups and role management that comes with asp.net?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ability exists to maintain the active domain groups there is no reason to maintain a local groups table isinrole can be used for group access checks

Comment: but the requirement from the client was that the user groups and security roles should not be part of the active directory ..

Comment: Based on the "is it a recommended approach" part of the question above I thought you were asking should I use active directory or not, if that's not the case please reword the question. For a database only approach look at the identity manager module